# Confusion about Spring MVC Controller method signature

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, methods, controller, return-type

Hi I am using Spring MVC 4.0.2. I am little bit confused while developing my `controller` methods. I can able to achieve same thing using two types different method signatures like given below. 
**1.**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model)
{
      model.addAttribute("user","Admin");
      return "home";
}
```

**2.**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login()
{
      ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
      model.addObject("user","Admin");
      model.setViewName("home");
      return model;
}
```

Now confusion is that what is different between this two methods? Which should I use? Is there any advantage/disadvantage of returning `String` or `ModelAndView`? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ModelAndView` contains both Model and the name of the view while `ModelMap` only contains information about the model. Returning ModelAndView seems more appropriate and is cleaner in my opinion. It also allows you to specifiy multiple views in one method, but I don't really see much use for that.